WLS choice of weight is sensitive to weights factoring
Related: How to determine weights for WLS regression in R?
On choosing WLS weights, I am trying to find the right variable to weight against. (eg. here hours, age and score can all be used as weights). When everything equates, I tried to check the weighted RSE. However, this metric is sensitive to the magnitude of the weight used. I am showing here what I mean:
weight_fac_multiplier <- 1:10
df <- data.frame(hours=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8),
                 age = c(25, 25, 30, 30, 30, 35, 40, 40, 40, 45, 45, 45, 50, 50, 55, 60),
                 score=c(48, 78, 72, 70, 66, 92, 93, 75, 75, 80, 95, 97, 90, 96, 99, 99))
for(i in weight_fac_multiplier){
    fit <- lm(score ~ hours + age  - 1, data = df, weights = i/(df$hours)^2)
    print(summary(fit)$sigma)
}

I think is it is a good idea to have a small RSE as a comparison, but having this scale difference issue is nagging as it is not absolute.
My understanding is so shallow, so any corrections and ideas are appreciated.

This comes down to asking what should the residual standard error be in the presence of precision weights, when the whole point of precision weights is that some observations are more precise than others and there isn't a unique standard error.
The original formalisation of WLS was for experimental-design settings where a weight of, say, 5, meant that an observation was the mean of 5 replicates.  For this setting, you want the estimated $\sigma$ to be the residual standard deviation for a single replicate, so the standard deviation for the observation that's a mean of 5 replicates is $\sigma/\sqrt{5}$ -- nothing else really makes sense when you have varying numbers of replicates.
So, you will get $\sigma$ (though not the coefficients or standard errors) being sensitive to the scale of the weights.  You can rescale. In your example, summary(fit)$sigma/sqrt(i) is constant.  Or you can scale your weights to have unit mean.
More usefully perhaps, you can consider some individual or average prediction you might want to do with the model and work out what the implied standard error of that prediction is.

Thank you for your input! Interestingly, WLS was a method to handle varying replicates, not heteroscedasticity. For your last suggestion, if I understood it correctly, do you mean to measure the prediction interval and make it smaller, based on that I can assess if the weight it good?

Yes, if you have a specific prediction interval or set of intervals that you care about, you can use the length(s) as a metric for precision of predictions.
